# Can you use 2 Bootstrap Themes at Once?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

This is probably elementary to most, but I'm going to ask anyway.

I have a great bootstrap theme I like for my application's "customer-facing" side, but I also have found another "admin" styled one for those back of the house operations.

Can the two be used at the same time inside of an asp.net MVC 5 project? If so, are there any tuts on this?  Tried googling this but maybe I'm not using the correct terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to accomplish what you are describing.

Simply have a layout page that will be used by the public section and in this page, include the customer-facing theme.

Then have another layout page that is only used in the admin section and in this page, include the admin theme.

Comment: See, I knew I was missing the big "on/off" switch answer.  Thanks, let me implement that and I'll obviously mark as the correct answer when I get it working...LOL.